# Unable to revoke inherited access of a related entity in Dynamics 365

Tags: crm, sharing, dynamics-365

I have an account with related contacts. When I share/unshare an account all related contact records are also shared/unshared. If I unshare a contact record and login to the user with revoked access to this record, this user still has access to it.

Comment: Who owns the account record (is it the user with revoked access to the contact)? How is your security model for reading contacts?

Comment: This question is too vague.. you have to go deep further yourself or give us more insights to help you..

Comment: I have an administrator security role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to a cascading [Entity relationship behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309412.aspx).

> When a one-to-many entity relationship exists there are cascading
> behaviors that can be configured to preserve data integrity and
> automate business processes.
>
> These configuration options are called cascading behaviors because
> they cascade down the hierarchy of related entities. For example, if
> deleting an account causes related opportunities to be deleted, what
> about the activities associated with the opportunities? In Microsoft
> Dynamics 365 the behavior defined in each of the entity relationships
> for activity type entities is that they are deleted as well.

Check what settings you have for Share on the relationships between account and contact. It's probably set to Cascade.

> *Action* - Share
>
> *Description* - When the referenced entity record is shared with another user.
>
> *Valid Options (Values)* - Active, Cascade, NoCascade, UserOwned.
>
> ***Value* | Description**
>
> *Active* | Perform the action on all active referencing entity records
> associated with the referenced entity record.
>
> *Cascade* | Perform the action on all referencing entity records
> associated with the referenced entity record.
>
> *NoCascade* | Do nothing.
>
> *UserOwned* | Perform the action on all referencing entity records owned
> by the same user as the referenced entity record.